# Regular expression for strings that cointains a and an even number of b's

Tags: regex, string, regular-language, language-theory

How to define a regular expression to feature the following language?

L = {w ∈ {a, b}* | w has an even number of b's}

I tried to create the related automaton:

[image]

and from that i tried to apply the algorithm to obtain regular espression from DFA and i get this formula: `a*ba*b`.

Could this be the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close but you need a `a*` in the end of your pattern.You also need the anchors `^` and `$` for specifying the start and end of your string.Then you can put all of your regex within a capture group and use `*` to match any even number if `b`, and an `a*` for zero number of `b`:

```
 ^((a*ba*ba*)*|a*)$
```

*Note*: `|` is a logical OR and makes your regex engine match `(a*ba*ba*)*` or `a*`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/w4V1ed4tlQctzZrR)

You can also make it more elegant but as you are not familiar very much with regex first i suggested the preceding pattern.

For example the following will works :

```
^(((a*b){2})*)a*$
```

Comment: What about this `(a*U(ba*b)*)*`?

Comment: @smartmouse Its pretty inefficient and also you have a `b` at the end of your pattern that in your case there is no constraint for the end of your pattern! as i added `a*` at the end of your regex.

Comment: Your new pattern works, but is a bit more complex than necessary.  I think `^(a*ba*b)*a*$` is sufficient.

Comment: Does `|` stands for `U` ?

Comment: @brian: yours is wrong: it accepts even string with odd b's

Comment: What about this `(a*(ba*b)*)*` ?

Comment: "Union: If R1 and R2 are regular expressions, then R1 | R2 (also written as R1 U R2 or R1 + R2) is also a regular expression." source: http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/nelson/courses/csc_173/fa/re.html . So `U` (union) stands for `|`

Comment: @smartmouse In regex we have not any `U` its in regular `NFA`. that is union! but yeah those are equivalent.

Comment: @smartmouse:  `^(a*ba*b)*a*$` does not accept a string with odd bs.  Not sure what you are talking about.  `(a*ba*b)*` means 0 or more instances of `a*ba*b`.  `a*ba*b` Has exactly 2 bs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution because i follow the algorithm for conversion from DFA to regular expression (done by pen):

```
(a*|ba*b)*
```

You can test it [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2jOPCPdp3MpB-sQZ) and you can learn about this algorithm watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBwx2PVicTY).